# Update account on win10

Tags: windows-10, email, default-settings, microsoft-account

I upgraded my laptop to win10 few months ago and I use it almost exclusively for web browsing, then two days ago I used one note application and I need to login with my account microsoft (an hotmail email address).
Now each time I start the PC it ask me to access with
hotmail account: it needs pwd email and I find all the settings before (desktop , browser settings, etc. )
"admin" account : no pwd and no default settings

How can I go back to the previous situation with no hotmail account and original settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings then Account info. Select Sign in with Local account instead.

Type in your current account password meaning your Hotmail account.

Next fill out a username and password and hit sign out and finish.

Now you can log into your account and it will be how you want it.

Comment: with "local account" you mean admin or hotmail one?

Comment: It asks you to log in with your Hotmail account everytime  you log in is because of this. So I suggested you do the steps above and it will no longer do that to you. You can still use OneNote and other applications while on a local account it will not require you to log into your hotmail account to log into windows anymore.